# Can someone explain how the external variable works in XQuery?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I see an XML node when I log $variable, but I'm not sure how $variable received the node and assume it has something to do with external.

```
declare variable $variable as element() external;
```

Comment: external variables have their values set by whatever code is calling it. You see a node likely because you defined it as the datatype element. Please put a bit of context around your inquiry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring an external variable in a query means that the calling application must supply a value for the variable when it invokes the query. The way in which this is done depends on the API offered by your chosen XQuery processor.